# Can I use 45 uF/5 uF in place of 70 uF/5 uF temporarily for air conditioning

Tags: hvac

My air conditioning is not blowing cold air today and I found the 70 uF capacitor measures about 1 uF. I happened to have one new 45 uF/5 uF at hand.

My question is: is it ok to use this one for a few days before the right one comes?

A Google search suggests the compressor can overheat but how bad is it for a few days in Texas at 100°F+ during the day?

Thanks.

Comment: " I fund [sic] the 70uF capacitor measures about 1uF." Which capacitor? Where? Can you show it in a schematic diagram? What voltage rating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

This is the induction start/run cap.  It will be harder starting at 40 uF than 70 uF as this is designed to provide the near 90 deg. phase shift for the 2nd winding.

But not as hard starting with 1uF.

But once started, both have 5 uF run caps.

Comment: It is more likely that the 5 uF capacitor is for a PSC fan motor and the 70 uF capacitor is for a PSC compressor motor. The 45 uF temporary replacement should be OK, but listen to it when it starts to cool. If it does not start within a few seconds, the thermal overload may kick in, and you don't want that to happen very often.

Comment: Not what Trane says https://www.trane.com/residential/en/resources/blog/air-conditioner-capacitors-what-they-are-and-why-theyre-such-a-big-deal

Comment: Dual capacitors with similar values are usually PSC run capacitors: https://www.ato.com/air-conditioner-capacitor. Here are some schematics showing dual run capacitors for fan and compressor, and a separate larger value start capacitor for units so equipped: https://www.caretxdigital.com/air-conditioner-dual-capacitor-wiring-diagram/

Comment: Presumably your 70u capacitor degraded at some point to 45u before reaching 1u.  It worth a shot provided the new cap has the same voltage rating.

Comment: Thanks. The AC unit has been running for 2 days without any obvious problem. I will put the new capacitor in once its arrived.